# Programmatically composing a chain

Tags: gatling

I would like to be able to programmatically compose a chain, for later inclusion in another chain.  I know it can't be that hard, but I seem to be missing something.

In theory, I should be able to do something like this:

```
var c = ??? // the part I can't figure out
List( 1, 2, 3 ).foreach {
  c.exec( http("Fetch something").get("..." + _ ) )
}
```

That is, I expect to be able to create a chain, then populate that chain in a loop, rather than hard-coding the chain in the source code.

My biggest struggle, I think, is knowing what to assign to `c`.  I had assumed that it should be

```
var c = new ChainBuilder()
```

but according to the [documentation](http://gatling-tool.org/api/gatling-core/com/excilys/ebi/gatling/core/structure/ChainBuilder.html) I have to pass it a list of actionBuilders and the next action, implying that it is not possible to build an empty chain and then build on it in a separate statement.

Is there any way to make my `.foreach` loop work the way I intend it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
import bootstrap._
```

and then

```
var c = bootstrap
```

But then the loop must be modified, like so:

```
List( 1, 2, 3 ).foreach( x => {
  c = c.exec( ... )
})
```

The reason has to do with the fact that you have to do what chaining does.  When you have

```
foo()
.bar()
.blip()
```

The result of the whole expression is the return value from `blip` and not `foo` - which is obvious when you think about it - so the variable that we are attaching to has to move as nodes are attached.

I hope someone, somewhere, besides me, finds value in seeing this example.